# Use Apicontrollers in MVC3 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project with Vs2010 and MVC4. (mainly Apicontrollers). Now the project is ready to deploy into production. The problem is that the client don't want to go with MVC4 even though there is a go-live license from Microsoft. The only new feature I used in this project from MVC4 is webAPI.

1. Can I use APIcontrollers in MVC3?
2. If yes How can I implement API controllers in MVC3 project?
3. What troubles will I face if I downgrade to MVC3 from webAPI standpoint (like :routing,hhtpconfiguration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. You can get web API with Nuget to you MVC3 project
3. Don't think you'll have any troubles, web API comes in separate dll that is independent of MVC dlls

Comment: Thank you very much.Is Web API Nuget fully supported. The client will agree only on proving that it is fully supported.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'fully supported', but Web API is still in beta as far as I know.

Comment: Web API is a fully supported product.

Comment: Microsoft as a whole generally does not support pre-release software like Web API.  Product teams sometimes make best-effort attempts to support customers using pre-release software, but that's usually at the discretion of the product team, isn't considered "proper" support, and isn't guaranteed.  (There are exceptions to all of this, but this is the rule of thumb.)